# create image from html

Tags: php, gd

i want to create an image from html, i couldn't use painty since it is outdated and no longer working and i want something similar.
i have already tried to create image using GD library like this

```
<?php
$html_code = "<b> this is the body </b> "; 
// Create the image 
 $img = imagecreate("300", "600"); 
 imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,0); 
 $c = imagecolorallocate($img,70,70,70); 
 imageline($img,0,0,300,600,$c2); 
 imageline($img,300,0,0,600,$c2); 

$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255); 
imagettftext($img, 9, 0, 1, 1, $white, "arial.ttf", $html_code); 

// Display the image 
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
imagejpeg($img);
```

but it doesn't "compile" the html tags and prints them in the image as text.

Best Regards

Comment: You mean it prints '<b>this is the body</b>'? That's normal. This is the job of the web-browser to render the html markup. There are some hints on the imagettftext page of the php doc. http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagettftext.php

Comment: `imagettftext` doesn't take HTML as its input but plain text - so you can't do it like this.

Answer (score 3):

the GD lib does not have the ablilty to render html-code and draw it on the image. if you want to draw bold text you need to use bold font, e.g. arialbd.ttf

Comment: i don't only want to draw bold font, i want to draw images inside images, br tags as new lines, italic and such things, how to render them before drawing the image ?

Comment: i'm afraid it's not possible. all you can do with GD library are described here (http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). you should draw all stuff with the functions provided by GD

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you can't render HTML without a browser.

A longer answer is that you can render HTML in a browser but you can't easily automate capture of a screenshot (there are [activeX widgets](http://www.xuebrothers.net/ie/activews.html) to do this - but activeX is such a bad idea). A better approach is to use a HTML client which can render to a suitable format - e.g. [xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/), there are also [online services](http://html2pdf.seven49.net/Web/) available for this